# What does "Power Calibration Area Error" mean when I'm trying to write a DVD

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, dvd-burning, imgburn

I'm trying to write a Windows 7 DVD iso to a DVD+R, single layer, 4.7GB disk. The source ISO file size is about 2.3GB. The burner is a hp DVD RAM UJ897, while the media is a Sony D31 DVD+R.

I tried to burn the ISO using various tools - Windows 7's native ISO burner, CDBurner XP - both failed without telling me why.

ImgBuner was a little more helpful & gave this error message:

[image]

This is the text which was shown:

```
W 21:09:31 Failed to Write Sectors 256 - 287 - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:09:31 Retrying (1 of 20)...
W 21:09:31 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
```

Does this mean my DVD burner is faulty? Or is it the medium? I've tried with 2 disks, both resulted in same error.

Full log:

```
I 21:05:29 ImgBurn Version 2.5.7.0 started!
I 21:05:29 Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate x64 Edition (6.1, Build 7601 : Service Pack 1)
I 21:05:29 Total Physical Memory: 8,181,360 KB  -  Available: 2,481,084 KB
I 21:05:29 Initialising SPTI...
I 21:05:29 Searching for SCSI / ATAPI devices...
I 21:05:31 -> Drive 1 - Info: hp DVD RAM UJ897 1.00 (D:) (ATAPI)
I 21:05:31 -> Drive 2 - Info: MagicISO Virtual DVD-ROM 1.0A (E:) (Unknown)
I 21:05:31 Found 1 DVD-ROM and 1 DVD±RW/RAM!
I 21:06:00 Operation Started!
I 21:06:00 Source File: C:\win7\Windows7Ultimate32bit.iso
I 21:06:00 Source File Sectors: 1,221,628 (MODE1/2048)
I 21:06:00 Source File Size: 2,501,894,144 bytes
I 21:06:00 Source File Volume Identifier: GRMCULFRER_EN_DVD
I 21:06:00 Source File Volume Set Identifier: 315f0800MS UDFBridge
I 21:06:00 Source File Application Identifier: CDIMAGE 2.54 (01/01/2005 TM)
I 21:06:00 Source File Implementation Identifier: Microsoft CDIMAGE UDF
I 21:06:00 Source File File System(s): ISO9660 (Bootable), UDF (1.02)
I 21:06:00 Destination Device: [0:1:0] hp DVD RAM UJ897 1.00 (D:) (ATAPI)
I 21:06:00 Destination Media Type: DVD+R (Disc ID: SONY-D21-00)
I 21:06:00 Destination Media Supported Write Speeds: 2.4x, 4x, 8x
I 21:06:00 Destination Media Sectors: 2,295,104
I 21:06:00 Write Mode: DVD
I 21:06:00 Write Type: DAO
I 21:06:00 Write Speed: MAX
I 21:06:00 DVD+R Reserve Track: No
I 21:06:00 Link Size: Auto
I 21:06:00 Lock Volume: Yes
I 21:06:00 Test Mode: No
I 21:06:00 OPC: No
I 21:06:00 BURN-Proof: Enabled
I 21:06:00 Write Speed Successfully Set! - Effective: 11,080 KB/s (8x)
I 21:06:01 Filling Buffer... (80 MB)
I 21:06:02 Writing LeadIn...
W 21:06:23 Failed to Write Sectors 256 - 287 - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (1 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (2 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (3 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (4 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (5 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (6 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (7 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (8 of 20)...
W 21:06:23 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:23 Retrying (9 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (10 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (11 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (12 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (13 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (14 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (15 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (16 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (17 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (18 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (19 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
W 21:06:24 Retrying (20 of 20)...
W 21:06:24 Retry Failed - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
E 21:06:33 Failed to Write Sectors 256 - 287 - Reason: Power Calibration Area Error
I 21:06:33 Synchronising Cache...
W 21:06:38 User opted to skip the 'Close Track/Session/Disc' functions.
E 21:06:38 Failed to Write Image!
E 21:06:38 Operation Failed! - Duration: 00:00:38
I 21:06:38 Average Write Rate: 0 KB/s (0.0x) - Maximum Write Rate: 0 KB/s (0.0x)
```

Note: reducing the burn speed hasn't helped either

Comment: Have you tried disabling the IMAPI CD-Burning COM Service?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg there isn't such a service.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/WDEc4.png

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows 7 but I can write CD. It's DVD that fails like this in Nero: "Power calibration error".

Answer (score 5):

The PCA is an area on DVDs that is used by the recorder to find out how powerful the laser needs to be to successfully write to the disc.  It's very close to the center of the disc.

Disc writers may report medium errors if there's a physical damage or interference issue with the lens or its ability to move, in addition to actual bad media.

Try the following:

- This might happen if the disk is upside down - it's an obvious one, but wouldn't hurt to check.
- Clean the drive with a cleaning disk, or gently blow it with canned air.
- Make sure the drive has any firmware update installed.
- Make sure you are not putting labels or writing on the disc before burning it.
- Ensure SATA cables connecting drive to motherboard are secure if this is a desktop.
- Remove any CD or DVD burning software (such as Nero) and try again.
- Try burning from a Linux Live CD in the very remote chance it's an operating system/software issue.

Beyond that, if you try a different brand of DVD-R and get the same results, replace the drive.

Comment: @Sathya Last sentance, he said he was using DVD+ media, so mabey trying a DVD-R might have different results?  It would also be trying different media in general.